# Razor DisplayFor of DateTime = Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

Recently I updated several of the referenced assemblies for my MVC 4 app and upgraded to MVC 5.1 as well. Not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Model

```
[Display(Name = "Start")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0t}")]
public System.DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
```

Now I am getting a strange error on a simple razor html helper

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.StartDateTime)
```

Gives the error: `Input string was not in a correct format`.

If you look at the value of that field in the debugger, it is of type System.DateTime and shows: `2/28/2014 10:17 AM`

Changing to a `@Html.EditorFor` renders the data time correctly.

My DisplayTemplates folder is empty.

Stack:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
   System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +14321177
   System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args) +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, ExecuteTemplateDelegate executeTemplate) +775
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelper(HtmlHelper html, ModelMetadata metadata, String htmlFieldName, String templateName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData, TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) +332
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.TemplateHelpers.TemplateFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression, String templateName, String htmlFieldName, DataBoundControlMode mode, Object additionalViewData) +333
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(HtmlHelper`1 html, Expression`1 expression) +151
   ASP._Page_Areas_Mobile_Views_LogTimeForPart_CurrentTask_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Chad\documents\Incite Systems\clients\hh metals\20 - development\otis\app\otis.web\Areas\Mobile\Views\LogTimeForPart\CurrentTask.cshtml:41
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +392
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +165
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +77
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +123
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +212
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +1161
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +639
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +828
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +1131
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +181
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +549
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +330
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +90
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +85
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +93
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +196
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +59
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Comment: How is your Model looks like?

Comment: @CodeMad Yeah, that would be good to add to the question :) See updates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try specifying the DisplayFormat attribute, for example (on your model property):

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
```

Edit based on edited question:

Your syntax in your display format is incorrect - it's missing a colon. Do this (notice the colon between the `0` and `t`):

```
[Display(Name = "Start")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:t}")]
public System.DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I added my model to the question. Need to format to show just time. So I have [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0t}")]

Comment: See my answer...just realized I did a stupid find/replace on my source code for this model and it wiped out the colons.... :(

Answer (score 2):

Did something stupid. Some of my `[Display(Name = "Start")]` had a colon : after the name to render it that way on a form. I used a replace in Visual Studio to replace the colons with "" which also removed the colons between the {0:t} formatstring annotations. `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0t}")]`. Sorry to waste people's time for my stupidity! Thanks all for the responses.

Comment: It led me to a fix on my code, so I appreciate it at least!